# Is it better to use css transform for positioning?

Tags: css

Using this to center the element:

```
.class {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Before I used to add a fixed width and height and use negative margins to center the element but doing that doesn't need a fixed width or height.

```
.class {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Transform browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: the fact we don't need to set a fixed width, avoids creating media queries

Comment: there seems to be two questions here. one about 'browser consideration and what is it? and another "should i use transforms or negative margins". Kindly decide which question you want answered.

Comment: updated, the browser support isn't needed as a question. updated with the browser support link. However, I do agree maybe this is just an opinion based question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform trick is applicable for newer browsers but your second method is applicable for older browser like ie7. So, if you want your website only for newer browser then you may go with transform but if you need to support older browser then you may go with your second code option.

Comment: OK according to this the browser support is really good, IE7 is it still alive? :) http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: http://www.theie7countdown.com/

Comment: transform is supported in ie9+ but your second code works in ie7+

Comment: @BhojendraNepal then transform is much more powerful i reckon

Comment: @rob.m this all depends on which browser you need to support, if you don't need to support older browsers then use transform, if you do then use positioning. While devs know older browser sucks, the general public is still using browsers like ie8

Comment: I understand and i guess is targetting but while I feel sorry, I won't care about 4.08% of IE8 users. But obviously depends on browser specs needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the width and height of the object you're trying to center, use transforms. Otherwise you can use which ever you prefer (keeping in mind the browser support already mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

I may guess that transform is more resource consumpting technique. I am not sure but I prefer second option if it is possible.

Comment: I would prefer to use transform if possible....

Comment: If transform is more resource consumpting technique, is this comparable to the need of writing extra lines of media queries for new fixed width?